# Telegram Bot deleteMessage function returns 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to write the telegram bot, and i need help here

`bot.deleteMessage(chat_id=chatId, message_id=mId)`

This code returns the following error: `400 Bad Request: message can't be deleted`

Bot has all rights needed for deleting messages.

Comment: `A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.`

Are you deleting older messages?

Comment: No, i'm deleting messages that was sent less then 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

A bot can delete messages:

**1. in groups**:

Only his own messages if he is not admin, otherwise also messages from other users.

**2. in private**:

only his own messages

---

in both the cases only if the message is not older than 48h.
Probably, since you said in comments messages aren't older than 48h, you can doing it wrong because of the first 2 points

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Message`. There are following [limitations](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) on deleting messages by bots:

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.
>     Returns True on success.

This can also happen if the `message_id` is not matching with the `mId` you have provided